# How to remove useless Gradle "merged dex #" log

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How to remove them as my CI log includes thousands of such lines, making it impossible to see anything else:

```
...
Merged dex #4471 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4472 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4473 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4474 (1 defs/0.8KiB)
Merged dex #4475 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4476 (1 defs/0.8KiB)
Merged dex #4477 (1 defs/0.8KiB)
Merged dex #4478 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4479 (1 defs/2.1KiB)
Merged dex #4480 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4481 (1 defs/0.8KiB)
Merged dex #4482 (1 defs/0.8KiB)
Merged dex #4483 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
Merged dex #4484 (1 defs/0.9KiB)
...
```

Comment: If you have a solution i'd be glad to hear it

Comment: No solution my friend @Geki, updated Android Studio to 3.1.3 and it seems the issue is resolved